# Does AngularJS $q service support .then(undefined) as a no-op

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

When putting conditional logic that governs whether a given continuation should be chained within a promise chain using the AngularJS $q service if figured it would be nice to be able to have some functions either defined or undefined depending on whether I want them to be included.

ex.

```
const maybeDoThis = yesNoMaybeSo ? 
    function (data) { return data; } : 
    undefined

doSomethingReturningAPromise()
    .then(doAnotherThing)
    .then(maybeDoThis)
    .then(doYetAnotherThing)
```

Is this possible using the $q service? I couldn't find the details within the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and testing it seems to be too much of pain because of the scaffolding needed to get a simple example setup.

If not am I best off just using an identity like function such as below instead of undefined?

```
function identity(value) { return value; }
```

Comment: Yes, Angular implements the Promises/A+ standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass either undefined or null into `.then()`, and it will effectively be ignored. For example, the following code will log out 'test':

```
$q.resolve('test')
    .then(undefined)
    .then(val => console.log(val));
```

By the way, if you've ever used `.catch(someFunction)` on a promise, this is the equivilent of calling `.then(null, someFunction)`, so you've actually been using this feature of promises for some time :)

Comment: "equivilent of calling `.then(null, someFunction)`" 
Oh, yeah I forgot about that. I'm glad that double null parameters works as well then.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is YES! This is possible. If you add a `.then(undefined)` angular doesn't fuss it just executes nothing and continues on with the rest of the statements.

I created a quick jsfiddle as proof of the functionality. Open the dev console to see the log info being displayed for the different conditions.

https://jsfiddle.net/dougefresh/ysvfgq3j/

I also pasted the code here for clarity but it runs nicely in the fiddle.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$q', function($scope, $log, $q) {
  $scope.maybeDoThis = null; 
    $scope.example = function(input) {
  $scope.maybeDoThis = input ? function() { $log.info('conditional function!');} : undefined; 
    $log.info('Button pushed');
    $scope.promise(true)
      .then(function(val) {
        $log.info('first then');
      })
      .then($scope.maybeDoThis)
      .then(function(val) {
        $log.info('third then');
      })
      .catch(function(val) {
        $log.info('catch!');
      });
  };

  $scope.promise = function(answer) {
    $log.info('promise run');
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (answer) deferred.resolve('TRUE');
    else deferred.reject('FALSE');
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <button ng-click="example(true)">
    CLICK ME TO RUN A FUNC
  </button>
  <button ng-click="example(false)">
    CLICK ME TO RUN UNDEFINED
  </button>

</div>
```